# MySQL - Keep getting records if last record is higher than previous

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I don't know if this concept is possible -- maybe in a stored procedure?

Consider a two row table:

```
`id` (int) | `value` (int) | `date` (datetime)
```

Lets say these rows exist:

```
1 | 3  | 2011-02-18
2 | 5  | 2011-02-19
3 | 12 | 2011-02-20
4 | 7  | 2011-02-21
5 | 8  | 2011-02-22
6 | 10 | 2011-02-23
```

I am trying to find trends, it is rather obvious for the human eye to recognize that the last three values are going up each day: 7 -> 8 -> 10. Is it possible to get the rows that remain in this pattern?

I'm thinking a stored procedure might be able to read through rows sequentially and find the first pattern (10 > 8), then continue checking until it no longer matches that concept: 
( 8 > 7 ), but not ( 7 > 12 ) so it would stop.

Any advice in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're after? Sequential increasing numbers in sequential days? Ideally you don't have some RBAR method to get your results

Comment: in Oracle you would use LEAD or LAG functions to check the previous or following rows.

Comment: @ Matthew -- these numbers reflect statistics. I'm trying to find out how long a statistic has gone up or how long it has gone down

Comment: @ Randy -- those functions would be great -- but I am using MySQL

Answer (score 1):

```
set @was:=null; 

select id from 
(
  select 
    id, 
    @was as was, 
    value as now, 
    (@was:=value) 
    from the_table order by date
) as trends 
where was is not null and now<=was limit 1;
```

Comment: After playing with it, I have got it close, is there anyway to make it only find the first trend? Right now it finds them all, which is great, but I need the last one only.

Comment: That gets the first record, not the first trend -- I'm wondering if there is any way to get the first trend